# Which vehicle manufacturer produces scissor jacks that have hex heads?

Tags: jack

I had a flat last night and went to put on the spare and the jack had seized! After a couple of people started working with it, we finally broke it loose, but since the primary screw had rusted I don't feel comfortable using it to support the weight of my car at all. Since I drive in the country pretty regularly, I don't feel comfortable not having a jack. I'm gonna go to the junkyard this weekend to try and find one in decent shape that fits in my spare tire well. I know from my shop days that some scissor jacks have a hex head on them, but can't remember which vehicles those came in. It would prefer this to the "hook through eye" type that my car came with.

Comment: I think when you go to the bone yard you'll find most places will have jacks out and ready for consumption ... you'll be able to pick and choose what you want, or describe what you want and they'll find it for you rather quickly. I don't have a direct answer to your question, so will just leave this comment.

Comment: Also try to find a hex head that matches your lug nut size - take your wrench with you.

Answer (score 3):

Because I don't have enough reputation to comment, I'll post here.

The only cars I know that had hex head jacks were the older (2004ish) Dodge Neons, and late 90's-early 2000s Mazda 626s. Other than cars, though, most RVs have hex-head jacks.

Good luck on your search!